# Variable in list - universal user interface, sys.argv

Tags: python-3.x, sys

I would like to make class, that will be universal for user interface. I would like, to have some form of list, that I will change for another program, to achive diffrent option from user.

I would like to have class variables like self.force in list, but I do not know how to use this place of list like a variable self.force but not like a argument of list (self.option_list[0][0]).

This code will not work, because I don't know how to solve this problem. It schow only, how I would like to solve problem of universal interface. If you use better way to handle sys.argv I'm open to suggestions.

```
import sys

class UserInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.option_list = [
            #[var, usr_name, def_val, choose_val]
            [self.force, '-f', False, True]
            [self.main_path, '-m', os.getcwd(), '-NEXT_ARG']
            [self.send_to_Kindle_dir_name, '-s',
                self.main_path+os.sep+'send_to_kindle', '-NEXT_ARG']
            [self.display_info, '-p', False, True]
            [self.display_help, '--help', False, True]
            ]
        for i in self.option_list:
            i[0] = i[2]
        for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
            for j in self.option_list:
            if sys.argv[i] == j[1]:
                if j[3] == '-NEXT_ARG':
                    if len(sys.argv)>i+1:
                        j[0] = sys.argv[i+1]
                else:
                    j[0] = sys.argv[i]
```

Comment: take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: The argparse module is great once you get to needing more than really basic command line processing.  The typical rule of thumb I have is when you start having optional arguments, and want something to simply stitch together help text, it simply becomes easier to use the lib.  Otherwise sys.argv is fine

Comment: @sehafoc Sure! Now what the OP is wanting to achieve (universal interface) really looks like rewriting [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Also [this article](https://realpython.com/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/) might be of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it, what I was looking for!